# How to Remove Apply Button in a Telerik RadColorPicker From Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, color-picker

I would like to remove the "Apply" button in the "RGB Sliders" tab of a [RadColorPicker](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/colorpicker/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) so that the functionality of setting a colour more closely resembles that of the "Web Palette" tab, which does not need an "Apply" button click for the colour to be set.

I would like this to be done in the code behind.

My RadColorPicker in its current form:

```
RadColorPicker colourPicker = new RadColorPicker();
colourPicker.ShowIcon = false;
colourPicker.AutoPostBack = true;
colourPicker.ShowEmptyColor = false;
colourPicker.PaletteModes = PaletteModes.RGBSliders;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by CSS.

```
'Code behind
colourPicker.CssClass="noApplyButtonColorPicker" 'ADDING A CSS CLASS HERE WILL ENSURE THAT IT APPLIES ONLY TO COLOUR PICKERS WHICH YOU CHOOSE TO.

/*CSS*/
.noApplyButtonColorPicker .rcpApplyButton
{
  display:none !important;
}
```

This will hide your apply button.

Sikandar

Comment: To add to that, you can add a CSS class to cascade through to make this specific to concrete instances:

colourPicker.CssClass="noApplyButtonColorPicker";

and

   .noApplyButtonColorPicker .rcpApplyButton
   {
   display:none !important;
   }

Comment: Yes, that will make it more specific.

Comment: You could edit your answer with that toe make it more visible